# Wordpress - Same images attached to multiple posts

Tags: wordpress

Is this possible? I have my images which are attached to different posts. I translated my site in 2 languages and just want to attach the same image to three different posts (english and 2 other languages).

Comment: There is also a wordpress-specialized version of this site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

No. Gostoms solution does not work because WP natively doesn't support an n-to-n relationship between media and posts. You need this: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/media-library-plus-plugin took me a while to figure out. Another alternative is the Attachments plugin available at WP plugin search.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I'm missing something here, but if you want to insert an image already uploaded an attached to a differant post, just bring up the add picture dialog as normal, and then select the "Media Library" tab. There you will see all the existing images and you can then just select show and insert into post for which one you want